# Dollar sign interpolation inside quotes in bash

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I am running this little test script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash

TESTCASE=$@
testHarness <<runTest
$TESTCASE
runTest
```

from the command line:

```
./test.sh "1092$212"
```

but the dollar sign is being stripped out.  If I escape it, it works.  But I thought the double quotes would protect me from needing to do this.  Can someone please help me understand what's going on and how to fix this?

Comment: The problem is that it's ambiguous--even for me as a human--what you want here, so the computer has no chance. Perhaps the bash interpreter is trying to get $212. Bash silently fails if you try to expand a variable that doesn't exist, thus the $ gets stripped out. Consider wrapping your variables inside brackets, e.g. "1092${2}12"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Variables are still expanded inside double quotes. If you want to avoid this behavior you should use single quotes instead.

Comment: Thank you.  This works.  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Yes. It was designed that way! It's actually quite useful to be able to expand variables inside a quoted string. It's a feature. If you don't want the behavior, use single quotes, that's what they were designed for.